# How to configure Routing, VPN and masquerading in Windows?

Tags: networking, windows, vpn, routing

I need to link a branch office to a new subnet. I'm doing something wrong. 
I try to be more specific:

---

I have this object virtually connected as follows:

**GW_U ---- S-OpenVPN ----- OpenVPN-C ----- GW_S**

where:

**GW_U**: main office gateway with Linux OS on which here is a the VPN server (OpenVPN-S) , a DHCP for the internal network 192.168.10.x and a firewall IPTables.

**GW_S**: gateway of the branch office with OS Windows 2003 Server, a VPN client (OpenVPN-C) and a DHCP for the subnet 192.168.8.x

Nodes IP in the network are as follows:

```
GW_U: 192.168.10.254
OpenVPN-S: 10.8.0.1
OpenVPN-C: 10.8.0.2
GW_S: 192.168.8.254
```

The VPN works fine but I can not to connect the two sub-networks (although I set the routing). Really I can operate only in one direction by enabling the masquerading (of GW_S) from one of the interfaces. If I enable masquerading on both interfaces (of GW_S) does not work!

On the Linux gateway (GW_U) I can enable the masquerading of all interfaces without problems.

I add some screenshot of the configured routing table and of NIC:

Routing Table (with my static routing) configuration: [image: http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/4702/74261.jpg]

NIC configuration: [image: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/1164/74263.jpg]

Comment: tnx for the image! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, I installed Linux! LOL! :P

and... this is not a "giving up" this is the only solution... in windows you can't enable Masqueraging on two "external" interfaces...!!! you need to have at least one "internal" interface.

and i think that THAT ANSWER can help other people with the same problem...